# Regex - Contains pattern but not starting with xyz

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a number pattern in a text file.

The file can contain values such as

```
12345 567890
90123 string word word 54616
98765
```

The pattern should match on any line that contains a 5 digit number that does not start with 1234

I have tried using `((?!1234).*)[[:digit:]]{5}` but it does not give the desired results.

Edit: The pattern can occur anywhere in the line and should still match

Any suggestions?

Comment: Poor wording -> "any line that does not start with 12345" + "The pattern can occur anywhere in the line"

Comment: "contains a 5 digit number that does not start with 12345"

Comment: How can a 5 digit number start with 5 digits? o,0  So what you wanted was a line that doesn't contain 12345 anywhere?  Or all 5 digit numbers that are not 12345?

Comment: I'm actually looking for 20 digit numbers but reduced it to 5 for the sake of simplifying the question. I can understand why it is confusing.

Comment: So what you are really after is "Any 20 digit number that does not start with 12345"?  From the wording of the question is looks like you are after an entire line ("Should match on any line that contains...").  Just a hint for wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would work, using `\b` to match word boundaries such as start of string *or* space:

```
\b(?!12345)\d{5}.*
```

Comment: The number doesn't necessarily have to be at the start of the line.

Comment: @MrWednesday: Oh, I misunderstood the requirement, then. Hang on.

Comment: That's the one. Thanks David.

Answer (score 4):

This regex should work for matching a line containing a number at least 5 digits long iff the line does **not start with '12345'**:

```
^((?!12345).*\d{5}.*)$
```

Short explanation:

```
                              ^((?!12345).*\d{5}.*)$   _____________
                              ^ \_______/\/\___/\/ ^__|match the end|
 _____________________________|    |    _|   |   |__  |of the line  |
|match the start of a line|        |   |   __|____  |
     ______________________________|_  | |match ey| |
    |look ahead and make sure the    | | |exactly | |
    |line does not begin with "12345"| | |5 digits| |
                                    ___|_____       |
                                   |match any|______|
                                   |character|
                                   |sequence |
```

---

*EDIT*:
It seems that the question has been edited, so this solution no longer reflects the OP's requirements. Still I'll leave it here in case someone looking for something similar lands on this page.

Comment: It appears start of line was not what he wanted, but hell, +1 for that ascii wizardry.

Answer (score 0):

try this, contains at least 5 decimal digits but not 12345 using a negative look behind

```
\d{5,}(?<!12345)
```